# Should I use redux for all the states I'm going to use in my app ? or I have to go along with setState some times?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, setstate

I have a big application with different features. What I want to know exactly is that should I overwrite all `setState()` functions that I have used with `redux` ? or in some cases I have to use `redux` instead ?

I mean is it bad to use `redux` for a simple `setSate` action ?

Comment: It is essentially impossible to offer an answer that isn't opinionated without knowing what your code looks like.  What you may think is a "simple" action may not be so simple at all.

Comment: I have a complex project so I installed redux now Take onclick a button as an example !  I want to change a state when that button is clicked . So should I use redux cause I managed the other states or simply use setstate ?

Comment: well, since the state is related to the entire component, rather than individual elements, and redux is designed to make managing the state easier, why would you sometimes use it for some elements and not for other elements within a single component?  wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having redux there in the first place?  again, completely opinionated.....

Comment: So you mean reducx is a state manager we have manage all the states in the entire project with that ?

Comment: You don't **have to** do anything (again, matter of opinion).  However, if you aren't using redux for certain elements, then you are purposely creating the kind of unreliable, untestable code that redux is designed specifically to stop.

Comment: Personally, I use redux for business logic state management. Anything that is related to interacting with the user, like a form, should be contained in the relevant components' state. Then, once submitted or on submit, this form data can go through the redux store, with or without syncing with a backend.

Answer (score 1):

It is ultimately up to you, but Redux is pitched as "global state management", which I interpret as "the state of the app".

Generally, the way I would build my state out would be to have Redux handle the data of logical/business structures (e.g. data coming from APIs), and as such I would pass in props to the components that use said data.

Once inside the component, I would use the component state to allow the component to manage its own logic for the things that it is concerned about, such as logic needed to conditionally render things or optimistic updates.

Some have even completely removed Redux from their applications with the advent of GraphQL + Apollo, allowing them to have server-side computations for what the UI would traditionally display (e.g. providing a boolean like `hasComment`) so that the UI doesn't have to perform that computation (backend is usually faster at these computations, too) and simply state `{hasComment && <Comment />}`. Another advantage of this approach is that other UIs could use `hasComment` without needing to implement duplicate logic.

Comment: That is exactly my concern.I had developed some components (including api calls or not) with state . and they work fine. Now I don't know if I have to handle them with redux and rewrite  the code again or just leave them?

Comment: and also if the redux main responsibility is to manage states why on earth  I should Iuse setState ?

Comment: Well, it's important to understand what global state patterns were invented to solve; before global state patterns like flux, redux, and the elm architecture came about, component state required you to define basically all information in your components and then pass them in as props to children components.

This led to patterns such as "smart & dumb" components, where you had components that only handled logic, while others only handled the presentation of said logic.

Comment: (cont.) this would inevitably lead to patterns where any two "presentational/dumb" components would require a "container/smart" component to manage the information that they share, which could lead to chains of props passed very deeply (potentially even up the component tree) in order to move horizontally to the component that needs that data, requiring a lot of boilerplate.

Redux and other global state management patterns evolved as a way to get rid of passing around props for "business logic" and instead let components simply worry about presenting the data.

Comment: Redux still requires a lot of boilerplate, which many don't like, and as a result hooks are very popular at the moment because they are a way to prevent deeply nested trees of Higher Order Components and (ideally) the reduction of boilerplate.

Again, GraphQL and Apollo (probably the most popular GraphQL framework at this time) introduce the ability to not have to ever even pass the business data to a middleman like Redux, rather connecting the component directly to the API, which simplifies error handling and reduces/eliminates the need for polling data via subscriptions. GQL is very neat.